# Streaming video plays on iOS devices but not Android

Tags: android, ios, video-streaming, m3u8

My app used to play HLS (m3u8) streaming video on both iOS and Android but recently something changed on our server (I don't know what) that has stopped android from playing the stream. It is still the exact same stream so I have no idea what could have changed. We introduced redirects on the server but it's only one so I'm not sure what the deal is. Do any of you know where I should look next to track down this issue?

Note: in the app I look at this txt file (it was not my choice for it to be txt) and parse out the m3u8 url for the video stream.

Additional Note: If you plug the URL into the android web browser directly it plays fine.

Here are some headers for those who are interested:

```
Remote Address:x.x.x.x:80
Request URL:http://xxxxx/videofeed.txt
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 NOT MODIFIED
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__atuvc=1%7C28%2C1%7C29; PRUM_EPISODES=s=1405606768407&r=http%3A//xxxxx/Unsubscribe.aspx%3Femail%3Duser@mail.net%26list%3Djom; jom-bigip=369103532.20480.0000; __utma=191791409.1763237517.1404757015.1408809372.1408840784.4; __utmc=191791409; __utmz=191791409.1404757015.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
Host:www.joelosteen.com
If-Modified-Since:Sun, 24 Aug 2014 00:46:51 GMT
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private,max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Date:Tue, 02 Sep 2014 18:28:45 GMT
Expires:Mon, 18 Aug 2014 18:28:46 GMT
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices:14.0.0.4762
Public-Extension:http://schemas.microsoft.com/repl-2
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SPRequestGuid:ddfb9b7b-5cb1-4644-88fa-52d776848b64
X-FRAME-OPTIONS:SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SharePointHealthScore:0
```

Here is the code I'm using to play the video in Android:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, VideoPlayerActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(VideoPlayerActivity.KEY_URL, url);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use WebView try change User-agent in your app:

```
    WebSettings webSettings = webviewHTML.getSettings();
    webSettings.setUserAgentString( "Android");
    webSettings.setUserAgentString( "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0");
```

or similar (as in your iOS app).

Comment: Here's the trick, the app is already in the Play Store and it WAS working. Now it's not and since the app is already out there I'm kind of stuck. I've been looking everywhere for an answer but I've got nothing yet.

Comment: IMHO, May be server parse useragent and ban to default android's useragent. Try implement this code in your app local (not in Play Store) and if this code will work fine, than trouble on server-side.

Comment: I don't know why this skipped my mind, but it's not in a webview, I'll post additional code details to the question.